# How to save the data from login to session in REST WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I tried to save the login details to session but I get the error that the session is `null` and I can't access it.

```
public void saveToSession(UserModel userInfo) {
    string id = userInfo.Id.ToString();
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Session["Id"] = id;
    context.Session["FirstName"] = userInfo.FirstName;
    context.Session["LastNAme"] = userInfo.LastName;
    context.Session["Username"] = userInfo.Username;
    context.Session["Email"] = userInfo.Email;
    context.Session["Role"] = userInfo.Role;
}
```

Do I need to do some other configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some start-up configuration

In ConfigureServices

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
})
```

And in In Application Builder

```
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Do you mean in WebConfig or what ConfigureServices?

Comment: are you using asp.net or .net core? I guess there might be a misunderstanding?

Comment: I am using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

REST generally requires that everything you need to perform the action is included in the request, so session is not enabled.  Enabling it is (IMHO) a little dirty.

[Enabling session state in Web API](https://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/enabling-session-state-in-web-api)

This works for ASP.NET Web API 5.x.  If you're actually using ASP.NET Core, it won't work (and please update your tags).

I recently used this technique *as a temporary measure* and have since removed it from my code because I've replaced it with a proper input that ties the request to the relevant data.  I suggest you try to do the same.

Finally, I called it "dirty" because it relies on reflection to assign a private field in a framework class.  Should the implementation change, it'll probably just silently stop working: either the field goes away, the `GetField` call returns `null`, and the check that follows stops passing, or the field remains but it's no longer used.  A less likely but still possible change is that the field's type is changed to something incompatible, and then you get exceptions at startup.